# Angular2 - browser_adapter.ts ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Location

Tags: typescript, angular

this is a quick question.. but I wish to get the current url of my app in various components, I don't want to derive this value from my routing component as that may be removed / changed in time. So I wish to work with the `Location` class in Angular2. In my component I add the following...

```
import {Location} from '@angular/common';
```

in my component I declare this in my constructor...

```
constructor(public translate:TranslateService, router:Router, private location: Location)
```

Now when I try to work with this I notice the error in my console... `browser_adapter.ts:82 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Location!`

The location class is located in `@angular/common`? I can't see how I have made a mistake here? I am using Angular2 release candidate 4. Here's what my code looks like altogether, I have edited this to make it less overwhelming:

```
import {Location} from '@angular/common';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    directives: [ ],
    pipes: [ ],
    templateUrl: 'src/main.html'
})
class MyComponent {

    constructor( private location: Location) {
        console.log(location);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To inject `Location` in a component you need to pass `ROUTER_DIRECTIVE` as directive in component metadata.

This enabled angular to inject the `Location` properly.

```
   import {Location} from '@angular/common';
   import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from  '@angular/router'

    @Component({
        selector: 'my-app',
        directives:  [ ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
        pipes: [ ],
        templateUrl: 'src/main.html'
    })
    class MyComponent {
    }
```

You could also get URL from router itself you by `this.router.url`

[Source](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/Location-class.html) : see the example section.