# Angular 2 + google analytics + router navigation

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

I am trying to add google analytics to my project but getting some navigation error, I am using new router, below is my code:

```
// app.component.ts
declare var ga:Function;
export class App {
    private currentRoute:string;
    constructor(_router: Router, _location: Location) {
        _router.events.subscribe((event:Event) => {
            if(event instanceof NavigationStart) {
                var newRoute = this._location.path() || '/';
                if(newRoute !== this.currentRoute) {
                    ga('send', 'pageview', newRoute);
                    this.currentRoute = newRoute;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
ERROR in [default] angular/src/app/app.ts:18:27
Argument of type '(event: Event) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NextObserver<NavigationStart | NavigationEnd | NavigationCancel | NavigationError> | ErrorObserve...'.
  Type '(event: Event) => void' is not assignable to type '(value: NavigationStart | NavigationEnd | NavigationCancel | NavigationError) => void'.
    Types of parameters 'event' and 'value' are incompatible.
      Type 'NavigationStart | NavigationEnd | NavigationCancel | NavigationError' is not assignable to type 'Event'.
        Type 'NavigationStart' is not assignable to type 'Event'.
          Property 'bubbles' is missing in type 'NavigationStart'.

ERROR in [default] angular/src/app/app.ts:19:23
Cannot find name 'NavigationStart'.

ERROR in [default] angular/src/app/app.ts:20:24
Property '_location' does not exist on type 'App'.
```

Comment: Hav you imported NavigationStart from @angular/router and  Location from @angular/common

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/38448830/652850 and  http://stackoverflow.com/a/38464412/652850

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal yesterday itself I did import NavigationStart & end & that resolved my issue.. :)

Comment: great !! added this as an answer as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please added import statement as well to see if this solves your issue:

```
import {Location} from '@angular/common';
import {NavigationStart} from '@angular/router';
```